# Flash button not reacting at all

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm making a game in Flash for school. I have a few dialog boxes that work just fine! Now I need a bigger one with more buttons and with the same code, I can't even get a trace reaction...

My code:

On the button itself:

```
okButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,MovieClip(parent).clickMyButton);
```

In the AS file:

```
public function clickMyButton(event:MouseEvent) {
trace("Halloooo");
}
```

Another question:

How can I close (remove from stage) a child dialog box (movie clip)

Answer (score 0):

Question answered:

I had a problem with and endless loop, that's why the button wasn't working!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AS3 its possible there is another movieclip ontop of the button and you can't click through. Also try MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN instead.